# How to pass data from directive function to service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to build a very simple toy 'calendar' application in angularjs. It really is very simple - a list of days with functionality to add 'appointments' to any day via a 'add appointment' link.

I've created my 'add appointment' link as a directive, which currently looks like this:

**Directive**

```
angular.module('calendarApp')
  .directive('newAppointment', function (Appointments) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/newAppointment.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.expanded = false;
        scope.expand = function() {
          if(scope.expanded)
          {
            scope.expanded = false;
          }
          else
          {
            scope.expanded = true;
          }
        }

        scope.newAppointment = {};
        scope.newAppointment.startTime = new Date();
        scope.newAppointment.endTime = new Date();
        scope.newAppointment.description = '';

        scope.createAppointment = function()
        {
          Appointments.addAppointment(scope.newAppointment);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

**Directive Template**

```
<a ng-hide="expanded" ng-click="expand()">Create Appointment</a>
<div ng-show="expanded">
    <h3>Create Appointment</h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newAppointment.description" /><br />
    <button ng-click="addAppointment(newAppointment)">Create Appointment</button>
    <a ng-click="expand()">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

**Service**

```
angular.module('calendarApp')
  .service('Appointments', function Appointments() {
    var appointments = new Array();

    // appointments fixture data removed for brevity

    this.appointments = appointments;

    this.addAppointment = function(appointment) {
      this.appointments.push(appointment);
      console.log(this.appointments);
    }
  });
```

Every part of my directive is functioning as I intended, except the 'add appointment' function. I cannot figure out how to send the appointment being created in my directive's scope to my service's addAppointment method. An object **is** added to my appointments array in the service, but it's a garbage/non-sensical one, not the one created by the form in the directive's scope.

How can I pass information back to my service from a directive?

Comment: In your addAppointment method you get appointment as argument but use booking! what is booking there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would help if you could explain/show what "garbage" object looks like, but it's obvious that you're not initialising your `newAppointment` object properly.

You're initialising it as string: `scope.newAppointment = '';`, while you should actually initialise it as object: `scope.newAppointment = {};`

Also, in your service you're pushing `booking` onto your appointments array, while you actually want to push `appointment`.

Also, your method is named `createAppointment` but you're calling `addAppointment` in your `ng-click`.

There's lots of other smaller problems and redundancies in your code.

Here's a reviewed and working version:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/dG73SbYe41OAY4Y4sgxG?p=preview)</kbd>

```js
app
  .service('Appointments', function Appointments() {
    this.appointments = [];
    this.addAppointment = function(appointment) {
      this.appointments.push(appointment);
      console.log(this.appointments);
    }
  });

app.directive('newAppointment', function (Appointments) {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'newAppointment.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var time = new Date();
      scope.newAppointment = {
        startTime: time,
        endTime: time,
      };

      scope.addAppointment = function(){
        console.log('Adding...');
        Appointments.addAppointment(scope.newAppointment);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<a ng-hide="expanded" ng-click="expanded=true">Create Appointment</a>
<div ng-show="expanded">
  <h3>Create Appointment</h3>
  <input type="text" ng-model="newAppointment.description" /><br />
  <button ng-click="addAppointment()">Create Appointment</button>
  <a ng-click="expanded=false;">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Stewie. I actually modified my problematic code to present as a smaller application for the sake of this question - accidentally introducing a series of naming issues that you correctly identified. Apologies. It's now working for me though - initializing my appointment as an object rather than string seems to have worked. I did try initializing it as an object originally but the app wouldn't run - I must have been doing something else wrong. Thanks for your snippet though, I learnt a couple of other neat tid-bits (setting scope properties directly through ng-click, etc). :-)

Comment: Your gratitude is appreciated, and you're welcome to post new questions. But let this be a reminder that you should always thoroughly review your code before posting it. That'll keep your questions from being closed, and will show your respect to the SO community.